# Count the number of customers in view in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, join, django-rest-framework

I have a multi-vendor eCommerce website, wherein seller dashboard I have to count the number of customers that has purchased that merchant product. I have tried somehow , but it is not correct.

I have written my logic in my view which is as follows:

```
class DashboardView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        count_1 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk']).count()
        count_2 = Token.objects.filter(user__is_customer=True).count()
        
# Having problem in this count_9
        
        count_9 = Order.objects.annotate(abc=Count('user')).filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk']).count()
        
        return Response(
            {'active_users_now': count_2,
             'total_customers': count_9,
                'total_orders': count_1,             
             },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...............
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):  
    ...................#other fields

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)

Class Product(models.Model):
   ............
   merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

I have two users model which are customers and sellers. I actually need to find out the number of customers which have purchased the products of a particular seller.

**Seller and Customer are one to one related with my CustomUser model:**

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    ................
    seller = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    ...............
    customer = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

I just need to write the correct SQL join to determine the counts.

**Also 2nd question is:**

I need to write an API to see all the customers with details who have purchased the products of that particular seller. However, if we can write my first question, we can write this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, one of the reasons why it was not working - you were filtering `merchant=self.kwargs['pk']` instead of `merchant_id=self.kwargs['pk']`.

A possible solution would be:

```py
count_9 = Order.objects.filter(
    order_items__item__merchant_id=self.kwargs['pk']
).values_list('user', flat=True).count()
```

Comment: I have used merchant=self.kwargs['pk'] before and it works. Btw can you tell me what is values_list gives??